# Javascript: Compute the number of product variants based on attributes

Tags: javascript, algorithm, e-commerce, variants

I want to generate all the possible variants a product can have based on the attributes like color, size, etc. I'm trying to implement the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324111/calculate-product-variants-based-on-option-groups-and-options) given by **profitphp** in javascript but not getting the desired results.

Here is what I implemented:

```
var data = [['red', 'blue', 'green'],['small', 'medium', 'large']];

result = generateVariants(data);
console.log(result);

function generateVariants(data,prefix) {
    if (typeof prefix === 'undefined') {
        prefix = '';
    }

    var result = [];
    var attribute = data.shift();

    $.each(attribute, function(key,val) {
        if (data instanceof Array && data.length > 0) {
            result = result.concat(generateVariants(data, val + ' '));
        }
        else {
            result.push(prefix + val);
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

*Expected Result:*

```
["red small", "red medium", "red large", "blue small", "blue medium", "blue large", "green small", "green medium", "green large"]
```

*Instead, I'm getting this:*

```
["red small", "red medium", "red large", "blue", "green"]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: All you need is to calculate cartesian product of your input array to get possible combinations. Perhaps this link can help. Look at the answer.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303989/cartesian-product-of-multiple-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: @Farooq Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Hey check my code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66521397/create-product-variants-based-on-attributes)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing the original array, clone it and pass the cloned array as argument.

```
 var data = [['red', 'blue', 'green'],['small', 'medium', 'large']];

    result = generateVariants(data);
    console.log(result);

    function generateVariants(data,prefix) {
        if (typeof prefix === 'undefined') {
            prefix = '';
        }

        var result = [];
        var attribute = data.shift();

        $.each(attribute, function(key,val) {
            if (data instanceof Array && data.length > 0) {




              // Instead of passing the original array, clone it and pass the cloned array as argument.
     _data = data.slice(0);



              result = result.concat(generateVariants(_data, val + ' '));
            }
            else {
                result.push(prefix + val);
            }
        });

        return result;
    }
```